# Inefficient SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm no MySQL expert, but I've managed until now to hack together something that works. Unfortunately, my latest bodged attempt results in the server dying, so obviously I'm doing something that is massively inefficient. Can anyone give me a hint as to where the problem is and how I might get the same results without bringing the whole site down everytime?

```
$sqlbest = "SELECT  
        wp_postmeta.meta_value 
      , wp_posts.post_title 
      , wp_posts.ID
      , (TO_DAYS(CURDATE())- TO_DAYS(wp_posts.post_date))+1 AS days 
    FROM  `wp_postmeta` ,  `wp_posts` 
WHERE  `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` =  `wp_posts`.`ID` 
  AND  `wp_posts`.`post_date` >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
  AND  `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` =  'views' 
  AND  `wp_posts`.`post_status` =  'publish' 
  AND wp_posts.ID != '".$currentPostID."'
GROUP BY  `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` 
ORDER BY (CAST(  `wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS UNSIGNED ) / days) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 4";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sqlbest);
```

It uses a post views count to calculate views/day for posts published in the last, then orders them by that number, and grabs the top 4.

I think I see that it's inefficient in that it has to calculate that views/day everytime for a few thousand posts, but I don't know how to do it any better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is an efficiency problem, as opposed to a simple syntax error, or something else in the code that causes an error? What happens exactly, do you get any errors?

Comment: also, you should run this query directly on your server and see what happens

Comment: try eliminating the 'order by' clause, see if it is any help

Comment: it works, so cant be a syntax. but when the query is run simultaneously by many users, the system collapses. run straight through phpmyadmin it works too, with an execution time of 0.36 seconds. As for the order-by clause  - how else would I grab the top 4 results? Thats kind of the whole point...

Comment: And please stop using the implied syntax, it is 19 years out of date!

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the need to call those date functions every time by either passing them statically into the query from your PHP server (which may not be synced with your database) or you can instead write a stored procedure and save the results of those date functions to variables that will then be used in the query.

Comment: I think I understand you there. But do MySQL date functions use that much resources?

Comment: When you use functions in your WHERE clause you basically make it impossible to use your indexes, so yes, it could potentially have a big impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  wp_postmeta.meta_value 
  , wp_posts.post_title 
  , wp_posts.ID
  , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),wp_posts.post_date)+1 AS days <<--1: DATEDIFF
FROM  wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON (wp_postmeta.post_id =  wp_posts.ID) <<--2: explicit join
WHERE wp_posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'views' 
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND wp_posts.ID != '".$currentPostID."'
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_value > 1   <<-- 3: extra filter
/*GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id */  <<-- 4: group by not needed
ORDER BY (CAST( wp_postmeta.meta_value AS UNSIGNED ) / days) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

I've tried to make a few changes.

1. Replaced the two calls to `TO_DAYS` with one call to `DATEDIFF`.
2. Replaced the ugly implicit where join with an explicit `inner join` this does not do anything, just makes things clearer. One thing it shows, **if** `wp_postmeta.post_id` is unique, then you do not need the group by, because the inner join will only give one row per `wp_postmeta.post_id`.
3. Added an extra filter to filter out the posts with a low view count, this limits the amount of rows MySQL has to sort.
4. Eliminated `group by` *this is only right if `wp_postmeta.post_id` is unique!*

Comment: thanks Johan - I was actually having trouble with two meta values being created for the views property of certain posts, so that was in there to deal with that. It would certainly be a better idea to clean the database and do it the way you have suggested. I've never been too sure of inner joins, so I'll do a bit of research into that; and the additional filter is an excellent idea. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i tried this and it returned the same 4 posts. Upon closer inspect, it seems that particular post had 6 entries for the meta_key "views", all the same number, but with different meta_id. strange....

Comment: made it SELECT DISTINCT instead, and increased the filter to >1000 posts. Workign, but I still feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here...